# Guides for installing Ubuntu 14.04 on a late 2012 iMac?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, hardware, mac

I'm having an awfully hard time getting Ubuntu to work on a late 2012 iMac. I partitioned, installed rEFInd, and was able to boot into Ubuntu, but the display is laggy, I get strange flickers, and I can't get my Apple Magic Trackpad to pair. In short, a lot of things are broken. Is there an up to date install guide for this iMac? All the guides I can find are outdated, and all the similar questions to this one are unanswered.

Comment: You might do better looking at questions about the individual issues you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer is that there isn't one. Will update this answer if one is released somewhere.